# Preserve new lines in YAML

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

How do I format a YAML document like this so that PyYAML can parse it properly?

```
Data: Some data, here and a special character like ':'
      Another line of data on a separate line
```

I know that the ':' character is special so I have to surround the whole thing in quotations like so:

```
Data: "Some data, here and a special character like ':'
      Another line of data on a separate line"
```

And in order to add a new line, I have to add '\n':

```
Data: "Some data, here and a special character like ':'\n
      Another line of data on a separate line"
```

Is there anyway to format the YAML document so I don't have to add the '`\n`'s in order to have a new line?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For multi-line scalars, you can use blocks. The character `|` denotes the start of a block. Use:

```
Data: |
      Some data, here and a special character like ':'
      Another line of data on a separate line
```

Answer (score 5):

If the extra newline that NullUserException's solutions is adding is a problem you should be using:

```
Data: |-
      Some data, here and a special character like ':'
      Another line of data on a separate line
```